Error FAILED! => {"msg": "'ansible' is undefined. 'ansible' is undefined"}
running this piece of code with ansible 8.7.0:

name: PRINT ANSIBLE
debug:
msg: "{{item.fileName}}"
loop: "{{ansible}}"

Throws me the error:
TASK [atos.atosbviaas.get_nexus_artifacts_info : PRINT ANSIBLE] ****************
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'ansible' is undefined. 'ansible' is undefined"}
Can someone help upon this?
the 'ansible' is defined as:
set_fact:
ansible: "{{ansible | default([]) + [{ 'downloadUrl':item.downloadUrl,'fileName': item.path,'md5':item.checksum.md5}] }}"
with_items: "{{ artifacts_info.json | json_query('items[*]')}}"
I'm expecting to get something like (from ansible 6.2.6):
TASK [atos.atosbviaas.get_nexus_artifacts_info : PRINT ANSIBLE] ****************

ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item={'downloadUrl': 'https://nexus.gemma-atos.net:8443/repository/ansible-release/atos-community-7.4.7.tar.gz', 'fileName': 'atos-community-7.4.7.tar.gz', 'md5': '888c64191c9076dda5d653e708572942'}) => {
"msg": "atos-community-7.4.7.tar.gz"
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item={'downloadUrl': 'https://nexus.gemma-atos.net:8443/repository/ansible-release/atos-gemma-7.4.7.tar.gz', 'fileName': 'atos-gemma-7.4.7.tar.gz', 'md5': '37cd9fed2a8c39e70051b2c50bc79517'}) => {
"msg": "atos-gemma-7.4.7.tar.gz"
